# Displaying google map as background in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

how can i display google map as a jumbotron  background? if `location = Branch 1` display a map of this location `1 Hacker Way in Menlo Park, CA 94025` from google map or if `location = Branch 2`  display a map of `755 N Mathilda Ave, Sunnyvale, CA 94085`.

i these two locations in .json file as:

```
1-  "location": "Branch 1"
2 - "location": "Branch 2"
```

> Branch 1 address 1 Hacker Way in Menlo Park, CA 94025 and  Branch 2 address 755 N
>   Mathilda Ave, Sunnyvale, CA 94085

I have the code also [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gates-2xkl7) to display header information, i have this code in the detail page as

```
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1 class="display-4">{data.first_name}</h1>
          <p class="lead">{data.Department}</p>
          <hr class="my-4" />
          <p>{data.location}</p>
          <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">
              Learn more
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
```

Json File looks like as follow

```
{
  "data": {
    "Table": [
      {
        "id": "1001",
        "first_name": "Adibayo",
        "last_name": "Aba",
        "Department": "IT",
        "location": "Branch 1"
      },...
]
}
}
```

Comment: what package are you using to load maps in react?is it google-maps-react?

Comment: @warmachine dont used any yet, open to use any whatever help me accomplish this

Comment: you need to use google-maps-react package with its auth key,load google map in react,once load ,i think  you can z-index the map as per your requirement

Comment: here is https://dev.to/jessicabetts/how-to-use-google-maps-api-and-react-js-26c2 ,post that will help you,but assuming you have latitude and longitude available for particular location